# Weird position for footer and header of UITableView with auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have a tableView where I would like to add a header and a footer (for the whole table, not for every section. So I did the following in viewDidLoad:

```
let footer = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
footer.addTarget(self, action: "add", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
footer.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "add"), forState: .Normal)
footer.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
footer.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

let header = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
header.addTarget(self, action: "add", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
header.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "US"), forState: .Normal)
header.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
header.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

tableView.tableFooterView = footer
tableView.tableHeaderView = header
```

I add the constraints (in viewDidLoad as well)

```
let viewsDictionary = ["footer": footer, "header": header]
tableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[header]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
tableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[header]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
tableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[footer]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
tableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[footer]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
```

and I get this:

[image]

When I do this:

```
let viewsDictionary = ["footer": footer, "header": header]
tableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[header]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
tableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[header(50)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
tableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[footer]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
tableView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[footer(100)]-0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
```

I get this:

[image]

I don't understand why I get those results. I checked the superView of header and footer and it is indeed tableView (as expected) but as you can see, it's like if there was something else in between (like another view). And when I place the footer at the bottom of its superView and the header at the top, I get indeed the header at the top (but like if it was in another view like before) and the footer is actually over the top of the tableView (I had to pull down the tableView to take the screenshot)

I'm a bit surprised as well that I have to manage the layout of the button if I simply use it as a footer or header. Shouldn't it be automatic?

**EDIT:**

I fixed it using the following for the footer:

```
footer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 68)
footer.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true) //or remove this line
```

It works (even if I don't understand why it wasn't working with the constraints) but I get a constraints error when I switch from portrait to landscape, go to the bottom of the tableView to make the footer appear and then switch back to portrait:

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174091da0 UIImageView:0x1743e7b00.width == UIImageView:0x1743e7b00.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174094000 H:[UIButton:0x14c600b60'>'(25)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17409bda0 V:[UIImageView:0x1743e7b00]-(1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x174384030 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1740949b0 V:|-(1)-[UIImageView:0x1743e7b00]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x174384030 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174099320 UIImageView:0x1743e7b00.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x174384030.leadingMargin + 1>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174093880 H:[UIImageView:0x1743e7b00]-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x14c603320'$ 1,09']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17409a9f0 H:[UILabel:0x14c603320'$ 1,09']-(2)-[UIButton:0x14c600b60'>']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174094b40 H:[UIButton:0x14c600b60'>']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x174384030 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170097110 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x174384030(83)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170098650 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x174384030(67.5)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174091da0 UIImageView:0x1743e7b00.width == UIImageView:0x1743e7b00.height>
```

And there I'm lost again as I didn't specify any constraint.

Answer (score 0):

It is automatic in width only which means no matter what width you set or width constrains you set for the view assigned to tableHeader(Footer)View the view will always occupy the whole screen width.

Actually you didn't talk much about what is the right layout you wanted in question. So generally I suggest you

1. init a `UIView`
2. set the height whatever you want
3. assign it to `tableHeaderView`
4. add the `UIButton` as subview

to see if you can achieve the right layout for tableHeader(Footer)View without autolayout

Comment: Well I would like to have a footer that looks like one of the rows (same height, same width) and is positioned as like if it was the last row (like a normal footer I guess). I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and return a customised view.

`-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
}`

Comment: No I don't want to have a footer for each section, I just want to have one for the whole table

Comment: Do u have only one section ?

Comment: Yes, just one section

Comment: So ,there won't be any problem in using the above function.

Comment: It actually stays displayed all the time on the screen, which is not what I'm looking for